# Proving an equation involving binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Prove that

$$\sum_{q=0}^v \binom{v}{q}\frac{q!}{v^{q+1}} = \sum_{q=0}^{v-1} \binom{v-1}{q} \frac{(q+2)!}{v^{q+2}}$$

Thanks.

Below are what I have tried:

Approach 1:

$$\sum_{q=0}^{v-1} \binom{v-1}{q} \frac{(q+2)!}{v^{q+2}}-\sum_{q=0}^v \binom{v}{q}\frac{q!}{v^{q+1}} \\
=\sum_{q=1}^{v} \binom{v-1}{q-1} \frac{(q+1)!}{v^{q+1}}-\sum_{q=1}^v \binom{v}{q}\frac{q!}{v^{q+1}}-\frac{1}{v}\\
=\sum_{q=1}^{v} \binom{v-1}{q-1} \frac{(q-1)!}{v^{q+1}}(q^2+q-v)-\frac{1}{v} \\
=(v-1)!\sum_{q=1}^{v} \frac{q^2+q-v}{v^{q+1}(v-q)!}-\frac{1}{v} \\
$$
It is shown by Mathematica that

$$ \sum_{q=1}^{v} \frac{q^2+q-v}{v^{q+1}(v-q)!}=\frac{1}{v!}, (Eq.1)\\
$$

then the equation follows. However, I failed to mathematically prove Eq.1.

Approach 2:

Trying to predict the summation result, e.g., $A(v)$. Prove that both the summations on the left and right are equal to $A(v)$ using mathematical induction. However, I cannot figure out $A(v)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  We like to see questions that the OP has put some thought into the problem.  This lets us help you better, because we can then know where you got stuck.

Comment: Any luck with induction? I couldn't get it to work. What exactly did you do on step three?

Comment: @TylerHG: No, unfortunately. Just use an identity of $\binom{v}{q}=\frac{v}{q}\binom{v-1}{q-1}$.